# How to prove that angular services are singleton?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I heard that angular services are singleton. How can i prove that. For vanilla javascript, i can create a singleton pattern and prove it like the below code.

```js
var mySingleton = (function(){
  var instance;
  
  function init(){
    var privateRandomNumber = Math.random();
    return {
      getRandomNumber : function(){
        return privateRandomNumber;
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    getInstance: function(){
      if(!instance) {
        instance = init();
      }
      
      return instance;
    }
  }
})();

var singleA = mySingleton.getInstance();
var singleB = mySingleton.getInstance();

console.log(singleA.getRandomNumber() === singleB.getRandomNumber());
```

Can anyone give me a code snapshot to prove Angular Services are singleton like I am doing in above code.

Comment: Create a service object that sets a random number, then retrieve it twice using $injector, compare the number. Or inject the service into two separate controllers and compare the number.

Comment: Can't you just require a service twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.service('mySingleton', function() {
    var privateRandomNumber = Math.random();
    return {
        Number : privateRandomNumber
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope, mySingleton) {
    $scope.randNumber = mySingleton.Number;
}

function MyCtrl2($scope, mySingleton) {
    $scope.randNumber = mySingleton.Number;
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   Hello, {{randNumber}}!
</div>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
   Hello, {{randNumber}}!
</div>
```

Yes, both the randNumber are same.

Comment: Thanks @sajeetharan, I understood it, so I am modifying the code little bit.

Comment: Mark as answer if it had helped